# HBase- Error while Connecting Java Client from Eclipse to HBase on EC2 instance

Tags: client, hbase

I am writing a Java client code on eclipse IDE to create a Table in HBase running on my EC2 instance. I have downloaded the Jar file via Maven. The HBase version is 1.2.0. But it is giving me the following error...

```
    Connecting...
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Connected 
Creating Table...
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=1200000, callDuration=3019412: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:159)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.executeCallable(HBaseAdmin.java:4110)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTableAsyncV2(HBaseAdmin.java:736)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.createTable(HBaseAdmin.java:590)
    at crud.Driver.main(Driver.java:38)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$MasterServiceStubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1580)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getKeepAliveMasterService(ConnectionManager.java:1737)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.MasterCallable.prepare(MasterCallable.java:38)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:124)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Can't get connection to ZooKeeper: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.checkIfBaseNodeAvailable(ConnectionManager.java:932)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.access$400(ConnectionManager.java:556)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStubNoRetries(ConnectionManager.java:1509)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation$StubMaker.makeStub(ConnectionManager.java:1551)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:99)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:51)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper.exists(ZooKeeper.java:1045)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.RecoverableZooKeeper.exists(RecoverableZooKeeper.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZKUtil.checkExists(ZKUtil.java:419)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.checkIfBaseNodeAvailable(ConnectionManager.java:921)
    ... 13 more
```

jps command on EC2 returns following

```
10912 RunJar
17156 Jps
7814 HeadlampServer
9062 NameNode
7816 Main
9640 JobHistoryServer
1290 Main
9708 NodeManager
9805 ResourceManager
7824 AlertPublisher
7923 EventCatcherService
9044 SecondaryNameNode
9140 DataNode
9879 HRegionServer
11706 Bootstrap
7899 Main
10908 RunJar
13181 QuorumPeerMain
9855 HMaster
```

Here is the Java Client Code.

```
package crud;


import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HBaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultScanner;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Admin;
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;


public class Driver {




    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        Configuration conf = HBaseConfiguration.create();
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "54.152.184.4");
        conf.set("hbase.znode.parent", "/hbase");
        conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");

        System.out.println("Connecting...");
        Connection con = ConnectionFactory.createConnection(conf);
        System.out.println("Connected \nCreating Table...");


        HTableDescriptor htable = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf("TbaleViaJar"));
        Admin admin = con.getAdmin();
        admin.createTable(htable);
        System.out.println("Table Created");

        con.close();
        System.out.println("Connection Closed.\nProgram Terminated");

    }


}
```

These are the maven dependencies added ion the pom.xml file

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hbase/hbase-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-common</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I see you have an IP address listed in your zookeeper quorum specification. Don't use IP addresses anywhere -- use host names. Make sure your IP addresses and host names are synched properly in /etc/hosts both on the HBase side and the client-side.

Comment: where I can get the host name?

Comment: do you mean the internal IP which comes up by `hostname` command?

Comment: Don't know how things work in the EC2 environment, but whatever is the host name that you use to refer to that machine. Basically avoid addressing it by IP and instead address it by that same host name everywhere.